# How to use localization in asp-for tag helper, when the model is an IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

In my view, the model is from type `IEnumerable<ApplicationUser>`. What is best practice to use the `asp-for` tag-parameter with this model?

What I mean is: when the model is from type `ApplicationUser` and we create a simple "Edit-All-Data"-model we simply can do something like this:

```
<label asp-for="Model.FirstName"></label>
<input asp-for="Model.FirstName"></input>
<label asp-for="Model.LastName"></label>
<input asp-for="Model.LastName"></input>
```

But now my model is an `IEnumerable<ApplicationUser>` (and I want to take advantage of localization with resources and `DisplayAttribute` of  `ApplicationUser`) and I want to write a table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th><label asp-for="??? FirstName ???"></label></th>
        <th><label asp-for="??? LastName ???"></label></th>

        <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var user in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@user.FirstName</td>
            <td>@user.LastName</td>
            <td><a asp-action="EditUser" asp-controller="Administrator" asp-route-id="@user.Id">edit profile</a></td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

How can I use the `asp-for` in the `<th>...</th>` tags? Did I miss something?

Comment: I'm not sure that that really makes sense because, in the case of an item or a simple model, you're actually getting the value of the specified property but you seem to be talking about getting the name of a property, which is quite different.

Comment: @jmcilhinney no not quite. when defining `label asp-for ` in asp.net core you actually get the propertyname (or the localized resource when using `DisplayAttribute`) in a label. when defining `input asp-for` you get the value in an input-field. (That's why I'm using `label` in `th`..)

Comment: Of course! D'oh!  Missed that. I guess one avenue of investigation would be to see how a `DataGridView` gets the column headers from its data source but that may not necessarily help, given that WinForms data-binding requires an `IList` rather than just an `IEnumerable`.  I guess another option could be to use `Model.FirstOrDefault()?.FirstName` if that syntax is valid in that context. The only issue there is that you get `null` if the list is empty.  Actually, the other issue is that you'd then get multiple enumerations of the list.

Comment: @jmcilhinney checked the `FirstOrDefault()?.FirstName`-thing. It works. for the empty list, I would stop showing the table: that's okay. But yes, the multiple enumerations still is an issue for me :/ is now an option as long as there's no other option :D

Comment: What do you mean with multiple enumerations? And second, you spent so much time writing the answer that you could have invested a few more seconds for a more telling title instead of tag-stuffing the title, which is not going to help you get answers faster in any way

Comment: @Tseng 10 times writing `<label asp-for="FirstOrDefault()?.[propertyname]"></label>` does 10 enumerations of the model when rendering the view. Doesn't it?  - Sorry, didn't knew how to write a more-telling title for this question. Wasn't my intention to tag-stuff the title... but yes, you are right. Thank you very much for your edit!

Comment: Actually it doesn't do any enumerations, as `FirstOrDefault()` doesn't do any advancement of the enumerator, and depending on the underlying type, its pretty performant (i.e. if the underlying type is an `IList<T>`, then it would just do an `list[0]`). But actually a simple `<label asp-for="FirstName"></label>` **SHOULD** be enough to make it work w/o getting an instance in the first place or an `<label asp-for="ApplicationUser.FirstName"></label>` (using the class name, not the `Model` property (sorry don't use Razor that often :P)

Comment: See https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/v2.1.2/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/First.cs#L39-L102 if you are interested in what `FirstOrDefault` actually does (on an IEnumerable. IQueryable is in different namespace, but you can find it same way)

Comment: @Tseng `<label asp-for="FirstName">` and `<label asp-for="ApplicationUser.FirstName">` won't work, since it searches for that property in `IEnumerable<T>` and throws an exception otherwise. - but yes, using `IList<T>` solves that issue. Thanks!

Comment: Well even if its not `IList<T>` only the first element ever will be taken from the enumerable. sure you may have little extra allocations for the enumerator itself, but you can ignore that unless its a hotpath with a few 10000 requests per second, which I doubt :P As long as the original type isn't  `IQueryable<T>` it should be all okay (enumerating `IQueryable<T>` will force it to evaluate (translate into SQL and execute/retrieve the results from the database in an sync way and hence blocking the thread for the duration of the execution)

Comment: A `<label>` is an accessibility element - clicking on it sets focus to its associated form control. Using a `<label>` in a `<th>` makes no sense.

Comment: @StephenMuecke i explained why I'm using it, didn't I? And it was not about using the focussing on click, I'm aware of it. When using bootstrap grid with `<div>`s instead of tables the problem remains the same. The question is about localizing!

Comment: I know - and that is why it was a comment, not an answer :) You can use `<td>@DisplayNameFor(m => m.FirstName)</td>` (`DisplayNameFor()` accepts `IEnumerable<T>` as a model and will output the value of the `[Display]` attribute)

Comment: @StephenMuecke .net core doesn't have `Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.FirstName)` for `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: You mean [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.htmlhelperdisplaynameextensions.displaynamefor?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: Ah I see, I tried with IList<T> not with IEnumerable<T> - my mistake. Nevertheless, it's not my intention to switch back to those HtmlHelpers. But: add it as an answer and I accept it - possibly it's the only 100%-correct solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178107/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-matthias-burger).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to provide an answer here, we just can use the extension-methods of `IEnumerable<T>`. The comments above from @jmcilhinney and @Tseng helped a lot

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th><label asp-for="First().FirstName"></label></th>
        <th><label asp-for="First().LastName"></label></th>

        <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    ....
</table>
```

I'm going to surround this with an `if (Model != null && Model.Any())` to ensure, this throws neither a `NullReferenceException` nor an `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

Answer (score -2):

I use a dummy instance for table headers (or the instance for a new element). It solves the problem with empty lists.

```
@{
    var newItem = new EntryViewModel();
}

<th>
    <label asp-for="@newItem.Code"></label>
</th>
<th>
    <label asp-for="@newItem.Name"></label>
</th>
```

Comment: I didn't downvote you (so maybe if you downvoted me now, stack overflow is not a place for revenges..!) - but to explain at least from my side why someone could've downvoted is, because this imho not a good solution. You create an instance, just to get the asp-for thingys.. you might have code in your constructor that could cause issues (at least for performance).

Comment: @MatthiasBurger if you have a list you might have hundreds of EntryViewModels created, so it is not a question of performance. Well, AI will reconcile (and fire) most of programmers)